# Can't seem to get updated state using Redux Toolkit

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-hooks, state, redux-toolkit

I'm making a React app using Tone.js and redux toolkit, and I'm having problems getting a function to read updated state. I seem to be able to update the state on a button click, but it isn't reflected in the function `thisWillRepeat` below.

In the code below I ideally will need `Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat` to run only once. `Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat` takes in the exact time of a scheduled event in the argument of a callback function and it can be controlled with `startStopHandler()`. I tried a number of things including adding `[theState]` as the second `useEffect` argument but it causes a complete mess as lots of extra repeats are scheduled. I'm sure there's something basic that I'm missing.

**The main app component**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import * as Tone from 'tone'

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { songActions } from '../store/index'

const Sequencer = () => {

  const theState = useSelector(state => state.theSong)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const startStopHandler = () => {
    dispatch(songActions.startStopHandler())
    !theState.isPlaying ? Tone.Transport.start() : Tone.Transport.stop()
  }

  const changeTheState = () => dispatch(songActions.updateAbitOfState())

  // why doesn't the state update in the console.log below after updating it successfully with buttons below?
  const thisWillRepeat = () => console.log(theState.drums)

  useEffect(() => {
    Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat((time) => { 
      thisWillRepeat(time)
    }, '8n')
  },[])

  return <> 
      <button onClick={() => startStopHandler()}>Play / Pause</button>
      <br/>
      A bit of state in the store has the value of: {theState.drums}
      <br/>
      <button onClick={() => changeTheState()}>Change the state</button>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(theState)}>Click to get the state</button>
    </>
}

export default Sequencer
```

**Store**

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialSongState = {
  isPlaying: false,
  drums: 'not changed'
}

const songSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'theSong',
  initialState: initialSongState,
  reducers: {
    startStopHandler(state){
      state.isPlaying = !state.isPlaying
    },
    updateAbitOfState(state) {
      state.drums = 'something new!'
    }
  }
})

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    theSong: songSlice.reducer
  }
})

export const songActions = songSlice.actions

export default store
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created a closure that captures the value of `theState` *at the time the component first rendered*:

`const thisWillRepeat = () => console.log(theState.drums)`

By definition, it can *never* point to values from later renders.

To read the latest state, you'd need to either:

- get access to the store directly and call `store.getState()` inside that callback
- Use a ref, assign `refObj.current = theState` in another effect above this, and then `console.log(refObj.current)`
- Move the logic outside the component into a Redux thunk, which also has access to `getState`

See Dan Abramov's post [A Complete Guide to `useEffect`](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) to better understand closure and how `useEffect` interacts with values.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How do you call ```store.getState()``` inside the callback? I've been struggling getting that to work..

Comment: oh never mind I think that works. Yes! Thanks